# why "return 100 if i < 10 else pass" is not valid in python?

Tags: python, if-statement

All;

```
def foo(i):
    return 100 if i < 10 else pass
    return 200 if i < 20 else pass
    return 1
```

Why this not works in python? I suppose this code may works same as:

```
def foo(i):
    if i < 10:
        return 100
    elif i < 20:
        return 200
    else: 
        return 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Define *Why this not works*. I get a syntax error if I try to define the function. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Why did you think this **should** work?  What part of the language manual suggested that `pass` work work here?  Please provide a link or a quote that shows why this **should** work.

Comment: I used to think the `pass` may have same meaning as in other language - `continue` or `next` in `for` or `NOP`, then I think `return 100 if i < 10 else pass` may be read as `return 100 if i < 10 else next line` which is a total mistake

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> `return 100 if i < 10 else pass`

you should read it as `return (100 if i < 10 else pass)`
so `pass` isn't a value

Answer (score 19):

In the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) you will see that the "ternary operator" should be like this:

```
conditional_expression ::=  or_test ["if" or_test "else" expression]
expression             ::=  conditional_expression | lambda_expr
```

and `pass` is a [statement](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements) not an expression

Answer (score 10):

read your code like this:

```
return (100 if (i < 10) else pass)
```

pass is not a value you can return.
The following code would work:

```
def foo(i):  
    return 100 if i < 10 else (200 if i < 20 else 1)
```

Comment: The parentheses aren't required in the expressions in either of the examples, but they do help make the code a little more readable.

Answer (score 2):

`pass` is a null operation i.e. when it is executed, nothing happens. It is useful as a placeholder when a statement is required syntactically, but no code needs to be executed. It should not be used as part of any logic.

Comment: Why the downvote? He was misusing `pass`, so I clarified its proper use.

Answer (score 0):

You should read you function as

```
def foo(i):
    if i < 10:
        return 100
    else:
        return pass
    if i < 20:
        return 200
    else:
        return pass
    return 1
```

`return 100 if i < 10 else pass` is not an "if" statement, this is a [ternary operator](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions)

Comment: `return pass` is not a valid statement. Simply `pass` in the else clause is what you want.